# Why is "Hierarchical view of the machine - plugins" always unchecked and can't be checked?

Tags: updates, system

Why is the option `Hierarchical view of the machine - plugins` always unchecked, and can't be checked when software update alert is available?

This has been happening for some time in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit system.

Would this problem affect the system's efficiency or safety?

Answer (score 0):

On the command line try:

```
sudo apt-get install libhwloc-plugins
```

And see what is says. Perhaps you need to install an additional package before it can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Nvidia graphics card?  I do and have the same siituation.  When I issue the command

```
sudo apt-get install libhwloc-plugins
```

I receive the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ocl-icd-libopencl1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-libopencl1-331
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ocl-icd-libopencl1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libhwloc-plugins
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I have an Nvidia graphics card (GeForce GTX 750 Ti), so I don't believe I want to remove

nvidia-libopencl1-331

There is a workaround here if you want to resolve this issue in Trusty:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ocl-icd/+bug/1247736